# How can I call my Logic App from API app in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Here is my task and may looks very simple. I've two APIs named API-A and API-B. I need to create a Logic App in between these two APIs. API-A should call my Logic App and Logic App should call API-B.

Please help me the steps to do it.

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

1) Create API App/Web API

2) Deploy API app to Azure or somewhere

3) Get the address of that. For example, http://example.com/api/values is the default.

4) Create Logic App

5) Add HTTP action, with the GET verb, and paste http://example.com/api/values to the URI.

6) Click + below your action and select POST, paste URI and in the BODY field click on the Body button to insert the content from the previous action - it should be there automatically.

Here, in the default API app, the first HTTP action will invoke the GET action of the controller which should return "value1", "value2". Then it send that content to the POST action of the second HTTP action.

[image]