# Logic App implementation using Push Triggers

Tags: azure, push, azure-logic-apps

From API A, using Push trigger, I need to call Logic App and doing some conditional check and then calling another API B.

Could someone guide me on this?

Comment: a little more details please, because basically it sounds like a basic thing to do in case of logic apps.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you did what i proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718668/how-can-i-call-my-logic-app-from-api-app-in-azure/36728025#36728025). But you need a conditional check somewhere? Then you need to click on + and add a condition block.

[image]

Comment: Yeah it was helpful. But here I need to use Push Triggers to invoke Logic App workflow

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate what do you mean by push triggers?